# how to get current time and then compare them using jquery 

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

this is my code:

```
    var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

alert(minutes+"/"+hours+"/"+month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
```

but , i think it hard to compare with two time ,

what can i do  ?

thanks

Comment: You usually need two quantities in order to perform a comparison. So you want to compare the current time to what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to know whether two Date objects represent precisely the same time, or are before/after one another, it's quite easy: just compare the two Dates via the `getTime()` method, which returns an integer timestamp for the object.  For example,

```
var date1 = myDate,
    date2 = new Date();
return (date1.getTime() < date2.getTime());
```

would return true if myDate is before 'now', false if it is now or in the future.

Comment: what is `mydate`? how do I creat it from the string `"16:30"` or `"4:30PM"`