# Compare two time values (hh:mm am/pm)

Tags: javascript, html

I have two time value which is selected from drop down box. The time format is `hh:mm am/pm`. I need to compare the two dates. I have done this code, but it doesn't work for me.

```
<select id="eventstarttime">
  <option>10:00am</option>
  ........
  <option>3:00pm</option>
 </select>

 <select id="eventstoptime" onblur="return checktime()">
  <option>10:00am</option>
  ........
  <option>3:00pm</option>
 </select>
```

The javascript method is

```
 function checktime()
{
    var start = document.getElementById("eventstarttime").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("eventstoptime").value;


    if(Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+end) < Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+start))
    {
        alert("End time should exceed the start time");
    }
    else if(Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+end) -Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+start)==0)
    {
        alert("Start time and end time cannot be same");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In PHP or JavaScript? [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) only accepts strings in RFC 2822 or ISO 8601 format. All other formats are implementation dependent.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Its php html and js

Comment: But do you want a script in PHP or in JavaScript? Your question title asks for a PHP solution, but your question body supplies a non-working JavaScript one.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I want script in js

Comment: Where do `dtEnd` and `dtStart` come from? They seem to be undefined.

Comment: @jeroen sorry,I have edited the code

Comment: @DamienPirsy The comparison of two times doesnt work,I think the comparison code is not correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add a 24h time `value` attribute to the `option` elements, like

```
<select id="eventstarttime">
  <option value="1000">10:00am</option>
  <option value="1215">12:15pm</option>
  <option value="1500">3:00pm</option>
</select>

<select id="eventstoptime" onblur="return checktime()">
  <option value="1000">10:00am</option>
  <option value="1215">12:15pm</option>
  <option value="1500">3:00pm</option>
</select>
```

you can easily compare them using

```
function checktime()
{
    var start = document.getElementById("eventstarttime").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("eventstoptime").value;

    if (end < start)
    {
        alert("End time should exceed the start time");
    }
    else if (end == start)
    {
        alert("Start time and end time cannot be same");
    }
    return false;
}
```

No need for JavaScript `Date` methods.

Comment: It wil be difficult for if time is 12.15

Comment: @Anaz: You can also add minutes to the `value` attributes. Edited code.

Answer (score 3):

You must separate `am` and `pm` from the time value by a `space`. Also in yor code variables `dtEnd` and `dtStart` are not defined.
In the else part just do it like as folows:

```
else if(end == start)
{
   alert("Start time and end time cannot be same");
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code.But if i remove the am and pm,U are saying that i need to add 12 if time is 5pm,ie 5pm = 5+12=17:00

Comment: Don't remove it. separate am an pm from integer value by a space.

Comment: You're relying on an implementation dependent format of `Date.parse`. It might not work in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML Code add space between 'hh:mm' and 'am/pm' in select **option** value

```js
 function checktime()
{
    var start = document.getElementById("eventstarttime").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("eventstoptime").value;


    if(Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+end) < Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+start))
    {
        alert("End time should exceed the start time");
    }
    else if(Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+end) -Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+start)==0)
    {
        alert("Start time and end time cannot be same");
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<select id="eventstarttime">
  <option value='10:00 am'>10:00am</option>
  <option value='3:00 pm'>3:00pm</option>
 </select>

 <select id="eventstoptime" onblur="return checktime()">
  <option value='10:00 am'>10:00am</option>
  <option value='3:00 pm'>3:00pm</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

try `strtotime` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$firstTime="10:00 am";
$secondTime="3:00 am";
$result =strtotime ($firstTime) > strtotime($secondime);
```

Comment: It just turned out the OP wants a script in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by PHP as bellow:

```
var d1 = "15:30";
var d2 = "15:36";
if (new Date(d1) < new Date(d2)) {alert('newer')}
```

Look the reference URls :

[jQuery/JS - How to compare two date/time stamps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174952/jquery-js-how-to-compare-two-date-time-stamps)

[how to get current time and then compare them using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595403/how-to-get-current-time-and-then-compare-them-using-jquery)

Using PHP you can do it like :

```
$time1 = strtotime("15:30");
$time2 = strtotime("15:40");

if($time1<$time2)
{
   echo "time 1 is smaller";
}
else if($time1>$time2)
{
   echo "time 2 is smaller";
}
else
{
   echo "both are same";
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: This looks like JavaScript to me.

Comment: @Hardik can you describe the contents inside the value d1.First segment is date,What does T means??

Comment: How you want to compare? i mean in PHP or JS?